# CSS layout: keeping the box width the same at different zoom levels

Tags: css

This seems like a simple question, but I couldn't find anything here/with search engines.

Let's first define what I mean by "same": I mean that if I put a ruler (the plastic one) next to the screen, the box would always, in different zoom levels, be the same width in centimeters (whatever that would be).

Let's also say that I'm talking about desktop browsers, since I don't want to complicate things by taking mobile into account. Also the browser should be wide enough to let there be some extra space for zooming.

Here is the box:
https://jsfiddle.net/a4be6ov5/

```html
<div></div>
```

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Now, if you zoom in/out, the box width will change. The browser's Developer Tools will always show that the width is 200px, because the way this zoom thing works. But what I would actually want, is that I would want it to match the initial width compared to that ruler of ours.

I can partly do that with viewport units, but I couldn't figure out to do it automatically by calculating something. I could only do it by manually defining all the steps at which to change the box width. This turns out to be cumbersome and there are too many steps to do it at. For example I could do this:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1500px) {
    div {
        width: 53vw
    }
}
```

... not very easy.

How to do this automatically for all the screen widths and zoom levels?

Comment: So you want to prevent someone zooming a part of your page? Why?

Comment: I would like to keep the width of the content area the same and let people just zoom the font size. Because I find this is the best way to keep/improve readability. Otherwise the content area spreads too wide and it's hard to read. This is the same when the typography people talk about max width for a good readability.

Comment: That's really up to the user to control. Most browsers have a way to switch between zooming the entire web page, or just zooming the text. For example, in Mac Safari a normal zoom is Cmd+/Cmd-, but zooming the text only is OptionCmd+/OptionCmd-. Firefox lets you set the default zoom behaviour to "text only" in its Settings area.

Comment: That's good for Firefox & Safari, but Chromium doesn't have that. So still need to do it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

What about having a slider on your page which alters the font size of your body element (or selected elements)?

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener("input", evt => {
  document.querySelector('.body').style.fontSize = evt.target.value + 'px'
})
```

```css
.a, .b {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.a {
  background-color: cyan;
}
.b {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<p>
Smaller <input type="range" min="10" max="22" value="16"> Larger
</p>
<div class="body">
  <div class="a">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vel aliquet mauris. Donec ipsum orci, ornare et tellus at, pretium aliquet nibh. Praesent quis tincidunt tortor. Integer ac varius nisi. Integer tempus varius justo. Quisque eget elementum sapien. Mauris id blandit arcu. Mauris dui erat, ultrices vitae ligula vitae, auctor cursus lacus.
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    Cras venenatis, nunc in tempus dictum, justo augue imperdiet nisl, id rutrum eros quam sed arcu. Maecenas fringilla diam in erat venenatis, sed sagittis elit tincidunt. Vivamus vel varius ex, id scelerisque ante. Donec ultricies, urna at aliquet gravida, urna erat porta nibh, vel semper magna urna eu dolor. Nullam condimentum ex ligula, a fringilla tortor eleifend in. Vestibulum congue eget lectus vel congue. Praesent eget malesuada est. Nulla nec semper nunc. Mauris id nulla molestie, varius turpis ut, pulvinar tortor.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for suggesting, but the thing is that I have a slider already. The problem is that it's hidden in the settings menu (and it needs to be there). It's not very useful for quickly zooming in and out. Often there is a case when some text is too small and need to be zoomed in just for that one case. And it cannot really be moved to forefront, because it would clutter things up there -- it needs to be hidden. So, sorry about that, cannot use the slider. :)

Comment: It seems to me that I might want to start looking at that viewport unit solution. Maybe I just make enough steps that would take care of the problem.